# How to fix "variable length array folded to constant array as an extension" without change in problematic code (due to assignment rules)?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

I am working on an assignment in C that is driving me crazy. I have to fill some functions out on a pre-coded program, and I am not allowed to change it. Everything was going fine, however, since a few days ago, I started to not be able to compile it because of the following error:

> error: variable length array folded to constant array as an extension

and it points me to a line of code that I am not allowed to change, neither I remember changing. Weirdly enough, I cannot remember what I changed last before it started throwing me the error (I tried to compile it as soon as I turned the code on, two days after I had last changed it).

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// function declaration
int free_linked_list(node *n);


// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];
```

This is the code that I think is relevant, taken from CS50x pset5. The error is thrown about the very last line (`node *table[N];`). All this code, except the function declaration "free_linked_list", came with the assignment, which means I cannot change any of it (except the number assigned to N, which I reverted to its initial value for this question), and I dont think I did. I guess my question is, is it possible that I have done something else in my code that would make the compiler throw this error in this line?? I am not even 100% sure I understand the error itself (there is one question about it in stack overflow, but I couldnt really understand the answer, and the solution passed through altering code that I cant for this assignment). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if it would be helpful to post more code.

Thanks!!

Comment: The warning is correct for C, although C++ would allow this usage of `N`.

Comment: What compiler? Is `table` really declared at file scope or inside a function?

Comment: @Lundin I think CS50 uses clang (I am not sure how (or if) i need to be more specific, i am just starting out... sorry :(  ), and `table` is indeed declared at file scope

Comment: Well, the problem is that the code isn't valid C since `N` isn't a constant expression. Clang apparently has a non-standard extension that it decided to toss in, though not without giving the warning.

Comment: Have you not been teached to use a source control system like Git to compare with the last working state? -- Please [edit] your question and add a [mre], with the emphasis on "complete", that shows the issue.

Comment: A plausible thing that may have changed to cause this warning to start being issued is the C compiler and / or compilation options being used.  Certainly the code doesn't belong in CS50, because it is not conforming C.  (Variable-length arrays are not allowed at file scope).  Apparently, however, some compilers will implicitly convert the VLA in that fragment to an ordinary array.  And if they do, they may or may not emit a warning about it, and if they emit a warning then that may, under the influence of compiler options, be promoted to an error.

Answer (score 1):

In standard C, *variable length array* variables are not allowed outside of functions due to this constraint from C17 6.7.6.2/2 (Array declarators):

> [...] If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

The `node *table[N];` in OP's code has static storage duration because it is defined outside a function, and it is a *variable length array* because of how its size is specified.

Whether or not an array type is a variable length array type boils down to how the size is specified.  From C17 6.7.6.2/4 (Array declarators):

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is **`*`** instead of being an expression, the array type is a *variable length array* type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope;<sup>145)</sup> such arrays are nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a *variable length array* type. (Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see
> 6.10.8.3.)

In OP's provided code, the size is `N`, but it is not an *integer constant expression* (see below) even though the variable `N` is fully defined with a `const` qualifier. Therefore, `node *table[N];` has a variable length array type.

An *integer constant expression* is defined by C17 6.6/6 (Constant expressions) as follows:

> An *integer constant expression*<sup>119)</sup> shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, **`sizeof`** expressions whose results are integer constants, **`_Alignof`** expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the **`sizeof`** or **`_Alignof`** operator.

In particular, variables (even those declared `const`) do not satisfy the above definition of an *integer constant expression*.

There is a get-out clause for extensions in C17 6.6/10:

> An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

Presumably, this is the extension that the compiler is warning about for OP's `node *table[N];` code. (Clang treats this as a warning, not an error, unless warnings are promoted to errors by the `-Werror` option.)

An acceptable way to fix the problem would be to specify the size with a macro instead of with a `const unsigned int` variable. E.g.:

```
#define N 26
```

But apparently OP is not allowed to change that. OP should seek clarification from their instructor, pointing out the problem in the supplied code. [EDIT 2023-03-08 - according to @nigh_anxiety's comment, OP is allowed to replace `const unsigned int N = 26;` with `#define N 26`, which would neatly solve their problem.]

Comment: Just a point of clarification - changing `const unsigned int N = 26;` to `#define N 26` or any other value is allowed.  The main things that can't be changed in the CS50 problems are the function prototypes and global data structures, as the automated testing tools are dependent upon them matching a particular signature.  Changing how `N` is defined does not prevent the automated tests from working.